# ios8 core data many to many not stored correctly

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, ios8

When I test one of my apps in ios8 beta 5 there is an issue with storing many to many relationships. There is a model card and a model topic. Cards belong to multiple topics and topics can have multiple cards.

When looking at the sqlite file the tables ZCARD and ZTOPIC are filled correctly. However the table Z_1TOPICS which contains the fields Z1CARDS2 and Z_4TOPICS is empty. 
Investigating the sqlite file of a ios7 Simulator the intermediate table Z_1TOPICS is filled correctly with Card and Topic id's. The code is the same for both, so this is most likely an ios8 issue.

Comment: Are you noticing problems in the app? Examining the SQLite files is not a very useful approach on its own.

Comment: The problem within the app is, that although the model Card has a property NSSet *topics, [CardObj topics] yields an empty set and vice versa. So the many-to-many relationship is simply not stored when running the app with ios8 devices. On ios7 devices all works fine.